# Displaying 3D models using C++

Tags: c++, 3d, modeling, action

I am currently designing an application in C++. Part of this application would be displaying changing 3D objects.

I have designed several bits of these 3D objects in Blender And also am aware of other programs with which to do this (Maya, etc.) However, I am unsure how to use C++ To display these objects, much less manipulate them in response to changing variables. What programs/approaches/disciplines do I need to learn/use in order to accomplish this task?

Comment: Well, I had a 3D engine in mind, using OpenGL, but the main problem is how to render and manipulate the Models I've already created programatically.

Answer (score 6):

Just about any game engine will do this for you — and much more. There are plenty of open source and commercial options out there. If you're not writing a game, a more general-purpose engine like [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) may suit. It only provides resource management and a rendering pipeline, and excludes game-specific cruft like AI and Physics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm going with the engine "Horde3D", at the very least to try it out. It seems like a lightweight choice which still keeps up with the functionality of other engines.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but you can export the 3d objects into [obj format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj) then load them into a C++ program with OpenGL libraries using http://sourceforge.net/projects/objloader/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 3DS Max to build those object, you can check out 3DS loader for openGL.
[This page](http://www.morrowland.com/apron/tut_gl.php) might be of some use to you

Answer (score 0):

Opengl is fairly low level, Another option you might want to look at is using a so called [Scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) for what is called retained rendering like [OpenScenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg)